# How to create a query that returns events occurring after current time and date in Swift using QuickBlox

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I have formatted the current date to be exactly same as format of chatEventStartDate in my quickblox account.  I have tried both when converting my date to a string, and leaving it as a date.

query.setObject(rightNow, forKey: "chatEventBidEndTime[gt]")

still returns every event, not just the ones starting later than the current time and date.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `String` or `Date` itself, but rather the time interval since 1 Jan 1970 (the start of the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). You can get this interval from a date like this:

```
let now = NSDate()
let interval = now.timeIntervalSince1970
```

and initialise an `NSDate` with an interval this way:

```
let interval = 1000.0
NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
```

Note that the type of `interval` is `Double`, not `Int`. I'm not sure if QuickBlox supports `Double`s. If it doesn't you can just convert it to an `Int` instead. You do lose the sub second precision like this though.

Comment: I wanted to follow up with this problem; I'm Kselvin's co-worker, and at first, neither of us could make heads or tails of this answer.
As it works out, QuickBlox can't handle comparisons of either strings or dates, aside from equal or not equal.  Thus, a date field needs to be replaced by an integer or float, if filtering based on before or after a date is needed.

Comment: @TimKokesh Well then my answer should work. An `NSDate` is under the cover just a `Double` and what I showed is how you can get that `Double`. It just represents the amount of seconds that have passed since 1970. Therefore if you want to compare 2 dates, you can just use this number and it'll work.